# Android Studio пишет, что переменной присвоено значение null, но она нигде не используется

Tags: java, android

Вопрос назрел случайно, когда перешел с Eclipse на AS. Компилятор пишет предупреждение (указал в топике). Но меня это смущает. Смысл вот в чем. Есть некий класс, я получаю его экземпляр. Использую его методы. После использования переменную, которая получала этот экземпляр обнуляю (=null).

```
MyPreferences pref = new MyPreferences();
pref.loaddata();
...использую методы класса MyPreferences
pref = null;
```

Вот на последней строчке AS предупреждает. Но раньше я читал такую фразу, что "Android не любит утечки ресурсов поэтому освобождаем переменную....и присваивали ей null".
Помогите разобраться как правильно писать... спасибо.

Comment: тег [android studio] указывается для вопросов по работе и проблемам непосредственно с этой IDE. Ваш вопрос к таким не относится.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В том и интерес области видимости и управления памятью в JVM. 
К примеру, Вы выполняете в своем методе все вышеописанное, после выполнения кода и выхода из метода, ссылки на объект теряются и через время он уничтожается сборщиком мусора.
По сути, Вы дописываете лишнее, на что AS и указывает.
Совсем другая история, если `MyPreferences pref` Вы укажете вне метода, переменной класса. Вот тогда `pref = null;` действительно необходимо для обнуления ссылок для последующего уничтожения объекта сборщиком мусора.

```
private void myMethod() {
    MyPreferences pref = new MyPreferences();
    pref.loaddata();
    ...использую методы класса MyPreferences
}
```

против

```
public class MyClass extends NotMyClass {
    MyPreferences pref;
    ...
    private void myMethod() {
        pref = new MyPreferences();
        pref.loaddata();
        ...использую методы класса MyPreferences
        pref=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Чуть-чуть опередили меня с ответом) да всё верно. Эта строчка будет считаться redundant - излишней, так как сборщик мусора и так сделает это работу, можно даже проверить вызвав его System.gc(); , например в разных циклах активити и потестриовать, где же всетаки данные убегают, вот тогда и понадобится использовать = null, чтоб понять как происходит освобождение памяти. С меня+1, за быстрый ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Установка `null` лишь указывает сборщику, что вы объект не используете. Это не вызывает GC сразу же и т.п.

Как VAndrJ правильно написал, всё зависит от видимости переменной. Вот только его пример не должен использоваться в реальном проекте:

```
public class MyClass extends NotMyClass {
    MyPreferences pref;
    ...
    private void myMethod() {
        pref = new MyPreferences();
        pref.loaddata();
        ...использую методы класса MyPreferences
        pref=null;
    }
}
```

Это проблема архитектуры. Сложно представить кейс, когда такое могло бы понадобиться. Обычно поля класса живут вместе с самим классом (консистентность, все дела). И когда у вас уже не будет ссылки на сам объект, то всего его внутренние поля будут уничтожены.

По поводу же установки переменных в `null`, порой это даже вредно. Если вы в играх будете всегда явно устанавливать объекты в `null`, то gc будет работать дольше, так как надо больше освободить. Чтобы оптимизировать в этом отношении игру, необходимо использовать пулы объектов, чтоб gc на них не вызывался вообще.

Вообще, почитайте [хорошую статью от ibm](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html). В ней ясно дают понять, что порой зануление ссылок может даже сделать хуже.

Comment: Согласен, что не должен использоваться, но данный пример показал для наглядности и понимания разницы.

Comment: Proxy примерно так работает

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei так в нём объект живёт всё время жизни самого прокси класса. И надобности в занулении внутреннего объекта нет.

Comment: я про структуру, а ну да, обнуления нет - верно. Но можно использовать, почему бы и нет, правильно же? и в этом будет смысл как раз по сути вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

принудительно присваивать `null`, когда поле более не требуется\класс не используется\активити закрывается, нужно только static-полям с завязкой на Context, чтобы избежать утечек памяти, так как имея static на внешний класс, сборщик мусора не уничтожит объект.
Так же нужно следить за закрытием курсоров, БД и тп. С остальным разберется сборщик мусора.

Answer (score 2):

Это ответственность сборщика мусора - находить неиспользуемые более объекты и удалять их. Принудительное обнуление переменных не дает каких-либо преимуществ и просто не имеет смысла, на мой взгляд.

Единственный вариант, когда это может потребоваться: при выполнении длительного процесса, когда локальный объект более не требуется, но еще находится в области видимости. Однако, на современных JVM даже такого рода обнуления уже не требуются, поскольку JVM самостоятельно может обрабатывать такого рода случаи.

```
void longProcess() {
  Object obj = new Object();
  operationsWith(obj);
  obj = null;
  doSomethingElse(); // длительный процесс, и чтобы не держать в памяти obj, мы ранее ее принудительно обнулили.
}
```

Однако этот код может быть написан иначе:

```
void longProcess() {
  {
    Object obj = new Object();
    operationsWith(obj);
  }
  doSomethingElse(); // принудительное обнуление уже не требуется.
}
```

По поводу обнуления ссылки, если она является членом класса: по-моему такие поля нужно просто сделать локальными переменными и при необходимости передавать их в функции.

Answer (score 0):

Многие не понимают, что Java - это чистый pass-by-value. Поэтому ваш

```
pref = null;
```

Означает только то, что переменная `pref` не указывает на объект в памяти. Что там в действительности произойдет с этим объектом в памяти - зависит от многих факторов.
Сама эта инструкция абсолютно бесмысленна и вы можете ее убрать. Если вы ее не можете убрать - у вас ошибка в другом месте.